# How can I map all instances of a CLR property type to a column type in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

In EF 6 I would just have used this in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("date"));
```

but I haven't been able to find an EF Core alternative, even after about two hours of googling.

Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: Take a look at the link. It's not so good as the EF6 and has to be run at the end of the `OnModelCreating` when all entity types are discovered. I'm pretty sure they will add something similar to EF6 in some future release.

Comment: Thank you, @IvanStoev, that answers my question nicely. We can only hope that with the supposed massive improvement on conventions in EF Core, they, or some public contributor, will eventually devise a way to do this as is done in EF 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create "Custom Conventions" in EF Core like this:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        property.Relational().ColumnType = "date";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something close to what you are looking for, but the example I found requires you to specify the Model and model property

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .Property(b => b.Url)
    .ForSqlServerHasColumnType("varchar(200)");
```

Here is the link to the doc and GitHub source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/data-types

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Modeling/FluentAPI/Samples/Relational/DataTypeForProvider.cs

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that. I did specifically ask how to " map all instances of a CLR property type".

Comment: ...and the same question has been asked on the docs page (with no answer)